# Bluetooth Programming Documentation for Cylceops Hammer Smart Trainer

Tags: xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am writing an application in XCode to control my Cycleops Hammer smart trainer. Some of the devices interface conforms to the GATT specifications found on Bluetooth's website so doing things like reading the current power output in watts isnt to bad. But it gets a little bit confusing when trying adjust the trainer's resistance. Does anyone have any experience working with this device or similar smart trainers? Any kind of documentation would be awesome.